# In Rails, how can I allow some html in a text area?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, formatting, erb

I have a Rails app (blog) that I am creating. Very basic stuff. In my content area I have a text area for the content of the post. I am needing to include some html in the text area (links, formating, etc).

```
<%= f.text_area :content %>
```

Is there another tag that I can use instead of text_area, that will allow me to do this?

Comment: Do you want your users to be able to type HTML into the textarea, or do you actually want to include your own HTML inside the textarea—ie, buttons that create links, etc?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you tried this in the views?

```
 <%= content.html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 14):

This is an old question but I guess there's a pretty straight forward view helper for this: **sanitize**. I presume you'd want to render the HTML tags entered by the user. For that purpose, save the content as a string and render as HTML using sanitize.

Example usage:

```
sanitize @post, tags: %w(strong em a code pre h2 h3 p blockquote ul ol li br),
                attributes: %w(href class)
```

The tags option allows you to specify which tags to use and same with the html attributes.

Comment: THIS is the correct answer!  The `.html_safe` versions would allow all html tags (including `<script>` tags!)

Answer (score 6):

The HTML safe method is actually .html_safe.  Just tested on a text field.

For example:

```
<%= @item.description.html_safe %>
```

Comment: How to avoid XSS scripting in this case, what if the user puts some script tags?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something similar to the **bold**, *italic*, ... options you get when posting in stackoverflow? If so, I would suggest [Markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/), a text-editor plugin for jQuery. Once you get this set-up, you'll be able to enter mark up in your text area (e.g. [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), bbcode, ...).  When you actually display the result on the page, you simply need to have Ruby parse the mark up language you chose.

E.g.

```
<%= @user.bio.bb_code %>
```

Using this method, you allow your users enter styled text in a safe fashion.

Comment: But how does one go about allowing only specific html? Like including lists, but excluding, I don't know, say, tables?

Comment: You are looking for Sanitize.  http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize

Answer (score 1):

With the forthcoming Rails 6, you will be able to use a new `rich_text_area` tag to create a rich text editor in your forms like this:

```
<%= form_with(model: article) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.rich_text_area :content %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

See [Action Text Rails Guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

[text_area_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M001736) is probably what you want.

Comment: I did get text_area_tag to work, however that still did not allow me to enter html in the text area.

Comment: If that helped but didn't fully answer the question then edit your question and add more information showing what you've changed. Add some mock output showing what you want to see output and we should be able to help you more.