# Ruby on Rails: Text field with default value containing html tags

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

In my RoR application, I have a form that contains a CKEditor text area so that a user can add their own styling to the text. What I want to do is add html formatted text to the text area so that this displays when a user goes to the form - so the text area will have formatted text as its default value.

Is this possible?

I have tried to do the following:

```
<%= f.cktext_area :message, rows: 10, value: "<bold>test</bold>" %>

<%= f.cktext_area :message, rows: 10, value: "<bold>test</bold>".html_safe %>

<%= f.cktext_area :message, rows: 10, value: ("<bold>test</bold>").html_safe %>
```

But none of these work. This is a seemingly simple task, but I cannot figure it out.

I have looked at the below links but they do not seem to address this same issue.

[Text Field Tag Placeholder Returning As Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481986/text-field-tag-placeholder-returning-as-value)

[In Rails, how can I allow some html in a text area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831072/in-rails-how-can-i-allow-some-html-in-a-text-area)

[How do I show formatted text in rails text area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176897/how-do-i-show-formatted-text-in-rails-text-area)

Comment: Have you tried `<%= f.cktext_area :message, value: raw("<bold>test</bold>") %>` ?

Comment: @Slava.K I have now, unfortunately this displays the text with no formatting.

Comment: You could try using css. `<%= f.cktext_area :messsage, value: 'text', class: 'bold' %>` and `.bold { font-weight: bold; }`

Comment: @mityakoval the problem with that is that I want a lot more formatting that just bold, bold was an example but I would require things like tables

Comment: ok. could you please try `<%= cktext_area_tag 'whatever[message]', @whatever.message.html_safe %>`?